# Parse byte array of multiple Avro records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro

I am trying to consume some topics. The problem is when producer serialized the data, he put several objects in one message. When i deserialize one message, I only get one object and lost others.

my schema is like this.

```
` "fields": [
        {
            "name": "instanceuid",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "s",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "t",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
`
```

And my deserialize class is from some demo like this

```
`public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            T result = null;

            if(data == null) {
                return null;
            }
            LOGGER.debug("data='{}'", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data));
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            DatumReader<GenericRecord> userDatumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(targetType.newInstance().getSchema());
            BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().directBinaryDecoder(in, null);
            List<GenericRecord> records = new ArrayList<GenericRecord>();
                 while(true){
                         try {
                                 GenericRecord record = userDatumReader.read(null, decoder);
                                 records.add(record);
                             } catch (EOFException eof) {
                                break;
                            }
                     }

           // result = (T) userDatumReader.read(null, decoder);
            LOGGER.info("deserialized data='{}'", records);
             result = (T) records;
            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SerializationException(
                    "Can't deserialize data '" + Arrays.toString(data) + "' from topic '" + topic + "'", ex);
        } finally {

        }
    }
}`
```

my code works if the message only contains one object.

Now I am trying to get my deserialized data, but i get error, it goes like this

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase"
```

my class implements Deserializer, so the deserialize method is T type.
so how can i return a T type with List type?

im not using confluent to register schema of something.

Answer (score 0):

> put several objects in one message

That's perfectly "valid", as far as Kafka is concerned. Now, you need to parse the bytes...

Without seeing the actual bytes of the data, it's difficult to answer why you get errors, but here are some hints.

1. If you have the schema, you should be using [Maven plugin](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/getting-started-java/) to create a class, and not using GenericRecord.
2. Kafka is commonly used with a Schema Registry, such as the one offered by Confluent. Confluent provides their own `KafkaAvroDeserializer` class, but there are also other implementations, so you don't ned to write your own. More specifically, BinaryDecoder will not work with Confluent-serialized producer data out of the box. As mentioned, you need to inspect the raw bytes, and cannot just assume you have a single Avro record in the data.
3. Your schema has no Avro array types, so therefore you already know your parser is messing up trying to do something with ArrayLists
4. You cannot return a `T`. You can return a class that has a List field. You would `implements Deserializer<ClassWithList>`, rather than have a raw interface...

Comment: i fixed this. The problem is that i cannot return a T for sure. After i inspect the raw bytes, i change the deserialize method to return a linkedlist and change all genericrecord to linkedlist .

Comment: Avro has its own array type, so you could use that. Otherwise, feel free to post your solution as a new answer